# Setting variable value if empty (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, default

I am trying to set a variable value if a form is not submitted (where the value comes from). Below I have:

```
if (empty($order)) { 
   $order = 'ORDER BY product_name DESC'; 
} 

else { $order=$_POST['order']; }
```

This always sets the value to 'ORDER BY product_name DESC' and ignores the form. Likely just a small issue but I can't pick it out.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `$order` is clearly always empty. Are you sure it is being set before you try to use it? Aslo, your code is insecure as it is wide open to sql injections.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: Use prepared statements to shield your application against SQL injections..

Answer (score 1):

```
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : 'ORDER BY product_name DESC';
```

Answer (score 0):

use isset

```
if (isset($order) && empty($order)) { 
    $order = 'ORDER BY product_name DESC'; 
}else { 
    $order=$_POST['order']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because $order is always empty. So go and figure out why $order never gets set or has a value of null or empty string. Or use isset($order).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset` :

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) { 
$order = 'ORDER BY product_name DESC'; 
} else { 
$order=$_POST['order']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$order` is not set before the if statement. Therefore `empty($order)` will always evaluate to true. I think you were looking more for the following:

```
if(empty($_POST['order'])) {
    $order = 'ORDER BY product_name DESC';
} else {
    $order = $_POST['order'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking of $order is empty or set, when you want to check if $_POST['order'] has a value. You should however not use the value submitted directly, but at least validate that it's something you expect it to be. Otherwise you'll make your application open for SQL injection.

```
$order = false;

if (empty($_POST['order']))
{
    // validate if $_POST['order'] has a valid value and set $order
}

if (!$order)
{
    // set a default order instead, as there either wasn't a POST-value or an invalid value.
}
```